# Weighted sample in Octave

Tags: octave

I've been searching everywhere and found nothing. Is there any way of performing a weighted sample in Octave?

That is, if we have two vectors e and v, where sum(v) = 1, a way of sampling n elements from e with probabilies v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to determine an index according to probability in vector 'v' then pick the corresponding index into 'e'. Thus, you need to use a [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). A simple way to do it is for instance:

```
    clear
    close all

    e = [10 20 30 40 50];
    v = [0.1 0.2 0.5 0.1 0.1];

    cdf = cumsum(v);

    n = 1000;

    E = [];
    for i=1:n
      r = rand;
      idx = find(cdf>r);
      E = [E e( idx(1) )];
    end

    hist(E)
```

Comment: Oh, right, I was trying something like that, but I was using v instead of cumsum(v). Thank you for the tip!